# Application not visible after adding it to AOSP build

Tags: android, android-source

I have added a two prebuilt apks in AOSP source code.

- Aurora store.
- FireFox

After building AOSP code Only Aurora store is visible on device but can't Found FireFox app after boot. It's also not listed in Settings->app

- I have checked that both app are present on Android device's file system

> /system/app/FirefoxBrowser/FirefoxBrowser.apk

> /system/app/AuroraStore/FirefoxBrowser.apk

Is there any reason why FireFox can't visible on device?

**EDIT:**
Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := FirefoxBrowser
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FirefoxFast_and_PrivateBrowser_108.1.1_Apkpure.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_ENFORCE_USES_LIBRARIES := false
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: My guess would be: AuroraStore is a pure Java/Kotlin app, it does not contain an .so file. Firefox on the other hand has a large set of .so file it depends on. BTW: Adding Firefox as system app has IMHO no advantage. AuroraStore may benefit from being a system app (for app installations) but for Firefox there is no advantage.

Comment: There is some wrong with the FirefoxBrowser.apk, and it can not be installed by the system. You can check the failed reason by logcat.

Comment: I have tried using putting Firefox app into /data/ folder using LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA) in Android.mk but same problem happens. I have noticed that when I install same apk using adb install I installs and visible on home and when i looks into /data/ folder there are some .so files in Firefox folders

Comment: @Robert there are some other apps which has .so files, I have checked it using extracting apk.is there any way to add apk with out platform signature?

Answer (score 0):

Which Android Version are you using and can you provide the `.bp` or `.mk` file you are using?

Can you extract the APK and check if the signature is correct?
`apksigner verify --print-certs FirefoxBrowser.apk`

If the signature is broken you might need the `preprocessed` flag in your `Android.bp`, or in your `Android.mk` try this:
`LOCAL_REPLACE_PREBUILT_APK_INSTALLED := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE).apk`

Another thing is the ABI architecture of your APK and System Image do not match. You should check the ABI of both, e.g. if your image is `arm64-v8a` but your APK is `x86` it won't work.

Comment: I have Edited my question with adding Android.mk, Also I have tried with replacing LOCAL_REPLACE_PREBUILT_APK_INSTALLED with LOCAL_SRC_FILES in Android.mk, but it gives an error that FirefoxFast_and_PrivateBrowser_108.1.1_Apkpure.apk is depends on PHONY target